# Refactoring: reducing duplication without creating flags

Tags: tdd, refactoring, dry

I don't know how to refactor a piece of code that differs from other in the number of conditions checked on an `if` clause. Let me show you a real world example I'm facing right now.

The only difference between the two methods is that on the inner `elseif`, it checks an additional condition on the new parameter.

Method 1:

```php
public function getKeysToInvalidateOnCreation($entity, $allKeys)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($allKeys as $key) {
        $entities_in_key = explode('+', substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')));
        $key_type = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_'));
        foreach ($entities_in_key as $entity_in_key) {
            if ($entity_in_key == $entity) {
                if ($key_type == self::GET_ALL_KEY || $key_type == self::CUSTOM_KEY) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                } elseif (strpos($key, 'id:') === false) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Method 2:

```php
public function getKeysToInvalidateOnModification($entity, $allKeys, $modifiedId)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($allKeys as $key) {
        $entities_in_key = explode('+', substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')));
        $key_type = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_'));
        foreach ($entities_in_key as $entity_in_key) {
            if ($entity_in_key == $entity) {
                if ($key_type == self::GET_ALL_KEY || $key_type == self::CUSTOM_KEY) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                } elseif (strpos($key, 'id:') === false ||
                          strpos($key, 'id:'.$modifiedId) !== false) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

What I would do is to extract all the inner code to a new protected method that would have the third parameter as optional, and then do the second check only if that parameter is set. But that has kind of bad smell for me: it seems like adding a flag to the method.

What would be the appropriate refactoring strategy?

Comment: Try moving the logic for checking if a key should be invalidated into its own function

Comment: Well, those two functions are the logic for checking if a key should be invalidated, in two different scenarios (creation and modification). I have "tdd-ed" both, so both are ok and pass all the tests, but now I'm in the "refactor" phase. How would that function look for you @Jack?

Comment: IMHO you are overthinking this - your own suggested refactoring is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP isn't a language I have much experience with, but as I understand it both loops are trying to filter the set of keys, so you can extract the structure of the loop into another method that accepts the conditions for filtering as an argument in the form of a function:

```php
private function getKeysWhere($entity, $allKeys, $condition)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($allKeys as $key) {
        $entities_in_key = explode('+', substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')));
        $key_type = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_'));
        foreach ($entities_in_key as $entity_in_key) {
            if ($entity_in_key == $entity) {
                if ($key_type == self::GET_ALL_KEY ||
                    $key_type == self::CUSTOM_KEY ||
                    $condition($key)) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This requires you use PHP 5.3 or above, in order to do things like pass functions as arguments and declare anonymous functions.

This is much more general and powerful than a boolean flag, because instead of picking between two set conditions, you can move the logic for whether to include the key into a separate function and separate the concern of filtering the keys from the concern of what conditions to filter them by.

Now, we define what the conditions for a key to invalidate on modification and on creation are as private helper methods:

```php
private function keyIsInvalidOnCreation($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'id:') === false;
}

private function keyIsInvalidOnModification($key, $modifiedId) {
    return strpos($key, 'id:') === false || strpos($key, 'id:'.$modifiedId) !== false;
}
```

And finally, we can define our two methods to get invalid keys in terms of this general method and these two predicates:

```php
public function getKeysToInvalidateOnCreation($entity, $allKeys) {
    return getKeysWhere($entity, $allKeys, 'keyIsInvalidOnCreation');
}

public function getKeysToInvalidateOnModification($entity, $allKeys, $modifiedId) {
    return getKeysWhere($entity, $allKeys, function($key) use ($modifiedId) {
        return keyIsInvalidOnModification($key, $modifiedId)
    });
}
```

The case for modification needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function in order to properly pass in `$modifiedId` to the predicate and turn it into a function of one argument to work with `getKeysWhere`. If you're using a library with support for common functional programming tools such as currying and partial application, you can use that here as a cleaner alternative to the anonymous function wrapper. Not sure how possible some of that stuff is in PHP though.

This is fairly heavily decomposed and may be difficult to grok if you're not familiar with functional programming patterns, but it cuts down on the duplication and generalizes well.

Comment: Once again, functional programming comes to the rescue! :-D

Answer (score 3):

So just for other PHP guys that may be struggling with functional programming I want to register here the steps I did following Jack's answer.

First I refactored each method to extract the condition so I could have an identical code base in both (note how the condition was extracted in both):

```
public function getKeysToInvalidateOnCreation($entity, $allKeys)
{
    $condition = function($key) {
        return strpos($key, 'id:') === false;
    };
    $result = [];
    foreach ($allKeys as $key) {
        $entities_in_key = explode('+', substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')));
        $key_type = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_'));
        foreach ($entities_in_key as $entity_in_key) {
            if ($entity_in_key == $entity) {
                if ($key_type == self::GET_ALL_KEY || $key_type == self::CUSTOM_KEY || $condition($key)) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

public function getKeysToInvalidateOnModification($entity, $modifiedId, $allKeys)
{
    $condition = function($key) use ($modifiedId) {
        return strpos($key, 'id:') === false || strpos($key, 'id:' . $modifiedId) !== false;
    };
    $result = [];
    foreach ($allKeys as $key) {
        $entities_in_key = explode('+', substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')));
        $key_type = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_'));
        foreach ($entities_in_key as $entity_in_key) {
            if ($entity_in_key == $entity) {
                if ($key_type == self::GET_ALL_KEY || $key_type == self::CUSTOM_KEY || $condition($key)) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

private function keyIsInvalidOnModification($modifiedId, $key)
{
    return strpos($key, 'id:') === false || strpos($key, 'id:' . $modifiedId) !== false;
}

private function keyIsInvalidOnCreation($key)
{
    return strpos($key, 'id:') === false;
}
```

At these moment, all tests are still green, so I can proceed to extract the common code to a private method:

```
public function getKeysToInvalidateOnCreation($entity, $allKeys)
{
    $condition = function($key) {
        return strpos($key, 'id:') === false;
    };
    return $this->getKeysToInvalidate($entity, $allKeys, $condition);
}

public function getKeysToInvalidateOnModification($entity, $modifiedId, $allKeys)
{
    $condition = function($key) use ($modifiedId) {
        return strpos($key, 'id:') === false || strpos($key, 'id:' . $modifiedId) !== false;
    };
    return $this->getKeysToInvalidate($entity, $allKeys, $condition);
}

private function getKeysToInvalidate($entity, $allKeys, callable $condition)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($allKeys as $key) {
        $entities_in_key = explode('+', substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')));
        $key_type = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_'));
        foreach ($entities_in_key as $entity_in_key) {
            if ($entity_in_key == $entity) {
                if ($key_type == self::GET_ALL_KEY || $key_type == self::CUSTOM_KEY || $condition($key)) {
                    $result[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And everything still green. Thanks Jack